# On remote push notification redirect to correct ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm struggling to get my iOS app to behave as intended when opened via a remote push notification (using Swift). What I want is, when the app is opened via tapping of a push notification, it should jump directly to a certain ViewController, but still maintain the navigation stack. And to complicate it further, the destination view controller depends on the push message. 
Example: *My app is closed and I get a push notification: "You got a new message". I click the notification and the app opens and shows the new message, instead of the regular initial view controller. If my app is open and I get a push notification, nothing happens.*

Comment: There're general problems that you'll see after you read the documentation, and there're particular problems that you'll see by analyzing your code. So my suggestion is: read the related documentation to understand why the behaviour is different when the app is at foreground, check your navigation code and make sure it does what you want it to do, if you have problems with it - add the code snippet and describe which part doesn't work as you expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, here are the methods to respond to a notification. Through these methods, you need to implement code that will present the appropriate view to your stack based on the notification.

To respond to notifications when the app is running  in the foreground OR background implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method. If you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it.

To respond to notifications when your app is running in the foreground NOT background implement the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method

To respond to notifications when your app is NOT running implement the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` OR `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

Comment: That was a great answer and it answers so many of my questions :) Thank you!

Comment: @rmp my application get crashed when it get redirection from push, can you please help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335204/push-click-app-opening-issue-unity-ios

Answer (score 11):

So what I ended up doing was:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if application.applicationState == .Inactive || application.applicationState == .Background {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
            let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dashboard") as? DashboardViewController
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: false)
            let destinationController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("notificationsSettings") as? AppSettingsTableViewController
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationController2!, animated: false)
        }
    }
```

So in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` I check which state the app comes from, and then I navigate to the viewController I want to present to the user. The reason I don't just go directly to the ViewController is because I want the navigation stack to be "intact" so the user can navigate back via the navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

I have done same this in **Objective C** based on **@NikMos** Answer

```
// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
#if defined(__IPHONE_11_0)
         withCompletionHandler:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {
#else
withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler {
#endif


    if (([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) ||
        ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        self.window.rootViewController =nil;
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        ScannerViewController *scannerVc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ScannerID"];
        [navigationController pushViewController:scannerVc animated:YES];
        NotificationVC * notificationVC  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationVCID"];

        [navigationController presentViewController:notificationVC animated:YES completion:nil];

         [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Do coding and enjoy coding. cheers :)

Comment: but I have tabbarcontroller also, in that case it get hide if use above code.

Comment: @anandprakash Please try without navigationController