# Push click - App opening issue - Unity iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

At present I have integrated server generated push notification and its coming properly in iPhone devices. When I click on push notification, its redirecting me towards my app but then after suddenly app get force closed at start up.

All the time its happening same. If I left loaded app into memory/dock and then I click on push notification then its working correctly.

But when app is completely closed then its generating issue in start up. I want to solve this otherwise there is no meaning of push notification implementation.

Actually I can't able to get debug log so that I can't able to trace an issue because at push notification click time, xCode can't remain in play mode.

Which ever things required, I am open to paste over here so please help me into this.

Comment: any error message ?

Comment: how to get error if I don't have access to debug log!! at push notification time xcode project can't remain in actual state to trace log.

Comment: Any help into this ??

Comment: Post your appDelegate code so we can see what you are trying to do.